# underlying.transferFrom in compound docs guide throws this error: ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string hardhat

Tags: javascript, chainlink, hardhat

I'm trying to lend to the compound protocol in an App I'm building.

Also following the compound doc & guide here: [Compound Blog Post](https://medium.com/compound-finance/supplying-assets-to-the-compound-protocol-ec2cf5df5aa)

After forking the mainnet locally and impersonating an address with large USDT, I'm now trying to lend to the compound protocol.

In my test, this line `underlying.transferFrom` always fails with this error: `ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string`

Any suggestions on what could be the reason? I've asked on the compound discord, and gotten no reply.

Also done lots of research, couldn't find a similar issue... don't know what else to do.

Below is a sample of my code

Dev Environment: Hardhat
OS: Windows 10

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "../interfaces/ICompound.sol";

contract CompoundController {
    mapping(address => mapping(address => UserInvestedTokenDetails))
        public UserInvestments;

    struct UserInvestedTokenDetails {
        uint256 tokenAmount;
        bool isExists;
    }

    function _setUserInvestments(
        address userAddress,
        address tokenAddress,
        uint256 tokenAmount
    ) internal {
        if (UserInvestments[userAddress][tokenAddress].isExists) {
            UserInvestments[userAddress][tokenAddress]
                .tokenAmount += tokenAmount;
        } else {
            UserInvestments[userAddress][
                tokenAddress
            ] = UserInvestedTokenDetails(tokenAmount, true);
        }
    }

    function supplyErc20ToCompound(
        address _erc20,
        address _cErc20,
        uint256 tokenAmount
    ) public returns (bool) {
        console.log("contract!");
        // Token being supplied to compound
        Erc20 underlying = Erc20(_erc20);
        // Token sent from compound in return
        CErc20 cToken = CErc20(_cErc20);
        require(
            underlying.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenAmount),
            "compound: transferring tokens from user failed!"
        );

        underlying.approve(_cErc20, tokenAmount);
        require(cToken.mint(tokenAmount) == 0, "compound: mint failed!");
        _setUserInvestments(msg.sender, _erc20, tokenAmount);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Also the test file as requested:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { BigNumber } = require("ethers");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const DAI = process.env.DAI;
const USDT = process.env.USDT;
//
const cDAI = process.env.DAI;
const cUSDT = process.env.CUSDT;

const USDT_WHALE = process.env.USDT_WHALE;

describe("CompoundController", function () {
  before(async () => {
    [deployer, user1, user2] = await ethers.getSigners();
    CompoundController = await ethers.getContractFactory("CompoundController");
    compoundController = await CompoundController.deploy();

    // FUND USERS ACCOUNT WITH PAYMENT OPTIONs TOKEN
    Usdt = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", USDT);
    Dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI);
  });
  describe("sendErc20", function () {
    it("should supply tokens to compound", async () => {
      let depositAmount = BigNumber.from("100000000000000000000"); //  100
      await hre.network.provider.request({
        method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
        params: [USDT_WHALE],
      });
      const signer = await ethers.getSigner(USDT_WHALE);
      await Usdt.connect(signer).approve(
        compoundController.address,
        depositAmount
      );
      let tx = await compoundController
        .connect(signer)
        .supplyErc20ToCompound(USDT, cUSDT, depositAmount);
      console.log(tx);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were the issues, ultimately:

- The USDT contract seems for some reason do not comply with the eip20 standard. It doesn't return a bool, so my interface for all erc20 contracts didn't match with their function.

Immediately I tested with DAI which was eip20 compliant, it worked.

- Also at some point, while forking the mainnet, my signer account (account I was testing with) didn't have the token (enough USDT) I was trying to supply to compound.

Comment: I had the same problem with USDT contract. You can use [SafeERC20](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#SafeERC20) if you need to keep the same interface on all your tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the user needs to approve the contract address to transfer on their behalf before you try to `transferFrom`.

Comment: Thanks Adam for checking this out. But i've done that already in my test. Before calling the `transferFrom` function in my contract.